# Knockout mapping.fromJS does not map all properties

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to mapping my viewModel every time that I call a ajax but the function mapping.fromJS does not mapping all the properties of the object.

I thought that maybe the problem was that the property was not declared, that I found an solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065536/knockout-not-all-properties-are-being-mapped), but I'm creating an empty viewModel from a templating that I get from the server using viewbag.

Here is what is happening:

[image]

The data object has the property "EntregaPai" with an ID and my viewModel has the value undefined, and then after the mapping:

[image]

the "EntregaPai" property still undefined rather than the others that was mapped as well.

**[EDIT]**

Here is my code:

```js
 // Seleção de linha da lista - ajustar dados
        self.selectRow = function (row, event) {

            self.canRefreshSubtipoPais = false;

            $.ajax({
                url: template.urlGet,
                method: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { EntregaId: row.EntregaId() },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    
                                           
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,self.formData);
                    
                    //Change the status of the form, not relevant
                    pbcCadastrosFramework.configuraEstado("S", self);
                    $(event.target.parentElement).addClass('success').siblings().removeClass('success');

                    
                    
                   
                }
            });
        };
```

I use the ko.mapping plugin for a lot of other forms in my project but only in this one the problem occurs.

Comment: Please don't (only) include screenhots of code, but actual code itself, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: The ko.mapping plugin updates model's properties using options calculated/passed during the initial call of `ko.mapping.fromJS`. So I think the problem is somewhere in your initialization code.

Comment: As far as I know you shouldn't bind mappings multiple times but update the vm. Not sure if that changes something related to your problem though.